# check if a given value is a positive number or float with maximum two decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, user-input

I am trying to implement a validation check for an input text control which should allow only a positive integer value or a float with maximum 2 decimal places.

Here is the fiddler with the approaches I've tried: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/49/

HTML

```
Enter Price: <input type="text" id="price"/> (Example: 10, 10.50. Do not include $ symbol.)
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="check1">Check Method 1</button> (Fails when the value is 1.00)
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="check2">Check Method 2</button> (Passes when the value is 45f)
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button" id="check3">Check Method 3</button> (Passes when the value is -10)
```

Code:

```
var price = $('#price');

$('#check1').on('click', function(){
   var val = $.trim(price.val());
    var num = Number(val);
    if (String(num) === val && num >= 0)
    {
        alert('Valid');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Invalid');
    }
});

$('#check2').on('click', function(){
   var val = $.trim(price.val()); 
   var num = Number(val);

    if (((typeof num === 'number') && (num % 1 === 0)) || parseFloat(val))
    {
        alert('Valid');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Invalid');
    }
});

$('#check3').on('click', function(){
   var val = $.trim(price.val());  

    if ($.isNumeric(val))
    {
        alert('Valid');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Invalid');
    }
});
```

Expectation:

The values that should be passed are positive numbers and float with maximum 2 decimals. (example 10, 10.50)

I looked at various answers in stackoverflow but non matched with my expectation. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I was going to vote up on @talemyn's answer below but one thing you should clarify for everyone is what you expect it to happen when someone supplies it with a value that could be rounded up. For example, if someone puts in 10.509 - do you want to accept that as 10.51 or do you say that it's invalid.

Comment: That's a good question @jgo . . . my assumption was that the value would be invalid, because it had 3 decimal points.  "Autocorrecting" it to a rounded value would definitely change the approach.

Comment: @jgo, in my application, when someone key in 10.509, I would like to show it as invalid.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I just voted up on @talemyn 's answer. 

I think the toFixed version presented by Erik below would've been viable but at the end of the day, that's still a "string" (i.e. pattern-based) based validate - not to mention the fact that it's actually comparing a String to a Number since toFixed() returns a string the num variable is a Number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are really looking for is that the value matches a pattern, not what it's value is.  For that, you are probably best off using a regular expression.  Specifically, this should catch the value that you are looking for:

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

That says:

- starting at the beginning of the value (`^`)
- match 1 or more digits (`\d+`)
- followed by an option decimal point and 1 or two digits (`(\.\d{1,2})?`)
- and no other characters before the end of the value (`$`)

That should enforce all of your rules, allowing you to perform a single check for validity, rather than multiple ones.

---

**Edit:** Here is an example of how to use it:

```
function checkNumber(sNum) {
    var pattern = /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
    console.log(sNum + " is " + ((pattern.test(sNum)) ? "" : "not ") + "valid.");
}

checkNumber("1");      // 1 is valid.
checkNumber("-1");     // -1 is not valid.
checkNumber("1234");   // 1234 is valid.
checkNumber("1.");     // 1. is not valid.
checkNumber("1.0");    // 1.0 is valid.
checkNumber("1.12");   // 1.12 is valid.
checkNumber("1.123");  // 1.123 is not valid.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. '-1' should be invalid. So, I changed the expression to /^\d+(.\d{1,2})?$/ and it works great.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that!  for some reason, when I was writing it, I thought you wanted negative numbers too.   :)   I'll take that part out, so as not to confuse anyone.

Comment: Don't forget to escape (`\.`) your `.` else it will accept numbers like 1x1 or 1a1 aswell.

Comment: @TVAvanHesteren - Oh dang!  Good catch!  I can't believe I missed that.   LOL   Fixed.

Comment: @talemyn, no problem :)

Comment: Note, if you are using this regex to check an input value on keydown (specifically when setting state on a React input component) I found it didn't match the period as the second set of digits were only accepting one or two numbers (and not none at all which might happen if there are no digits after the first time you enter a period). I slightly modified the digits to make it work for my use case: `/^\d+(\.\d{0,2})?$/`

Comment: @RBrill - Ooof . . . yeah, I don't know that I would ever recommend implementing something like this as key-based validation.  The change that you made fixes the issue that you encountered, but it allows the user to stop with a final value of `1.`, for example, which (I assume) would be considered invalid (as opposed to `1` or `1.0` or `1.00`).  I would only ever do this kind of validation on change or blur.

Comment: @talemyn Good catch! It does work very well for me onKeydown but I suppose I'll have to strip off any trailing `.` on blur (or however else I'm navigating away from an input field)

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine it would be:

```
var num = Number(val);

if (!isNaN(num)
    && num > 0
    && num == num.toFixed(2))
{
  // Valid
}
```